# Android - UI creation problem

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm very much a beginner in android environment.
I am trying to create a simple application with very few controls.
I arranged all the controls in UI and its looking good when I'm running in Samsung Galaxy phone.
But when I'm running the same application in Nexus, there's much gap at the bottom of the controls. Functionality is same.

How can I create the application that will adjust the controls as per the resolution of the phone?
Can some one guide me on this.

Comment: Check out droiddraw.org if you haven't yet, great tool for designing the UI. As for the question, I believe this will be helpful to you : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether this will solve the issue :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make 3 layout folders with name layout-small,layout-normal,layout-large.put ur xml files in these folders according to resolution.phone will automatically detect according to resolution.if u have any problem go with this link..

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

What pixel units do you use? It is recommended to use "dp" as they are recalculated according to screen resolution and pixel dencity.